# Date function doesn’t return all results in SSRS using SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I have a SQL Server stored procedure with one parameter `@par_date`.

Inside the procedure, I use the `EOMONTH` function to return last day of the month against current date, so the user will see the actual sales and monthly budget.

The SQL statements work fine, but when I run the procedure from SSRS, only one date the function doesn’t return the monthly budget but zero number.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Aziz. The more effort you put into your question, the more effort the community will provide in attempting to help you answer it. Have a look at [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)